# Adding one day to a date

Tags: php, date, datetime

My code to add one day to a date returns a date before day adding: 
`2009-09-30 20:24:00` date after adding one day SHOULD be rolled over to the next month: `1970-01-01 17:33:29`

```
<?php

    //add day to date test for month roll over

    $stop_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("2009-09-30 20:24:00"));

    echo 'date before day adding: '.$stop_date; 

    $stop_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 day', $stop_date));

    echo ' date after adding one day. SHOULD be rolled over to the next month: '.$stop_date;
?>
```

I have used pretty similar code before, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 420, accepted):

```
<?php
$stop_date = '2009-09-30 20:24:00';
echo 'date before day adding: ' . $stop_date; 
$stop_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($stop_date . ' +1 day'));
echo 'date after adding 1 day: ' . $stop_date;
?>
```

For PHP 5.2.0+, you may also do as follows:

```
$stop_date = new DateTime('2009-09-30 20:24:00');
echo 'date before day adding: ' . $stop_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
$stop_date->modify('+1 day');
echo 'date after adding 1 day: ' . $stop_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Thanks. Solved it as: $stop_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( "$stop_date + 1 day" ));

Comment: You should not use a variable in a string. You should use:`date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($stop_date . ' + 1 day'));` as in the answer that @w35l3y gave you.

Comment: You should add a call to date_default_timezone_set function before running this code.
For example add date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');

Comment: Error:  Call to a member function modify() on a non-object in <b>/public_html/untitled5.php</b> on line <b>72

Comment: You did something wrong, @hamish - https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php#example-2002

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DateTime::modifiy(). By the way, using "/usr/local/php74/bin/php" to execute php file. It just doesn't work.

Comment: it is "modify", not "modifiy" @GabeHiemstra

Answer (score 135):

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-12-31');

$date->modify('+1 day');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
```

Comment: This is a more recent -perfect- solution.

Comment: ...As long as it doesn't cause fatal errors when run on your host ;)

Comment: Don't apologize. Some people posted the dame answer 3 years after you did

Comment: You should add a call to date_default_timezone_set function before running this code.
For example add date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');

Comment: @LucaMastrostefano no, you should have the timezone set on your server...

Comment: this should be an accepted answer because it works for both latest date and any other date while the accepted answer only works for latest date. kudos

Comment: fatal error on my side.   probably only for new php servers.

Answer (score 92):

It Worked for me:
For Current Date

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 day"));
```

for anydate:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
```

Comment: thanks it worked for me.
Simplest of all solution given.

Comment: you don't need to repeat and nest `strtotime()` - it can handle everything in one call: `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . " +1 day"));`

Comment: Nice, This is the simplest solution! Thank you

Answer (score 34):

Simplest solution:

```
$date = new DateTime('+1 day');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: I like your way in a one liner `echo (new DateTime('+1 day'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Comment: @Aba I don't think your one liner works in older versions of PHP because I tried it and I got an error: `Unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR” error in PHP`

Answer (score 9):

Simple to read and understand way:

```
$original_date = "2009-09-29";

$time_original = strtotime($original_date);
$time_add      = $time_original + (3600*24); //add seconds of one day

$new_date      = date("Y-m-d", $time_add);

echo $new_date;
```

Comment: This will sometimes fail on daylight savings changes when the day length is not 24 hours.

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',date(strtotime("+1 day", strtotime("2009-09-30 20:24:00"))));
```

Comment: Thanks mate. It helped me.

Answer (score 7):

The `modify()` method that can be used to add increments to an existing `DateTime` value.

Create a new `DateTime` object with the current date and time:

```
$due_dt = new DateTime();
```

Once you have the `DateTime` object, you can manipulate its value by adding or subtracting time periods:

```
$due_dt->modify('+1 day');
```

You can read more on the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php).

Answer (score 4):

I always just add 86400 (seconds in a day):

```
$stop_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("2009-09-30 20:24:00") + 86400);

echo 'date after adding 1 day: '.$stop_date;
```

It's not the slickest way you could probably do it, but it works!

Comment: How do you deal with leap seconds when adding 86400 won't work as there's 86401 seconds in that day? (ok, I know it only happens every few years, but depending on the app this might be important)

Comment: Not all days have 86400 seconds in them.  In fact, in most places in the US there are 3600 fewer or additional seconds twice a year.

Comment: You can safely ignore leap seconds, since "Unix time" does. This is somewhat complicated, but read this article for more info: http://derickrethans.nl/leap_seconds_and_what_to_do_with_them.php

Comment: You should avoid this solution. Here is why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613338/date-returning-wrong-day-although-the-timestamp-is-correct

Comment: Do not add date by adding 86400 seconds to previous day! You will have bug in your code! This does not work on Daylight Saving days!

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with Doug Hays' answer, I'll chime in here to say that the reason your code doesn't work is because [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/strtotime) expects an INT as the 2nd argument, not a string (even one that represents a date)

If you turn on max error reporting you'll see this as a "A non well formed numeric value" error which is E_NOTICE level.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

function plusTimetoOldtime($Old_Time,$getFormat,$Plus_Time) {
    return date($getFormat,strtotime(date($getFormat,$Old_Time).$Plus_Time));
}

$Old_Time = strtotime("now");
$Plus_Time = '+1 day';
$getFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

echo plusTimetoOldtime($Old_Time,$getFormat,$Plus_Time);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code get the first day of January of current year (but it can be a another date) and add 365 days to that day (but it can be N number of days) using DateTime class and its method modify() and format():

```
echo (new DateTime((new DateTime())->modify('first day of January this year')->format('Y-m-d')))->modify('+365 days')->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

As we often receive ISO strings via an API from another time zone, we can make the conversion to local time on the fly:

```
// The machine local time is GMT+2, but we received a date at GMT+0 (UTC)
echo date(DATE_ISO8601, strtotime("-1 hour", strtotime("2022-08-17T23:25:51-00:00")));
// 2022-08-18T00:25:51+0200
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add one day to today's date using DateTime() and DateInterval() like this:

```
echo (new DateTime())->add(new DateInterval('P1D'))->format('Y-m-d');
```

OR a specific date:

```
$date = '2009-09-30 20:24:00';
echo (new DateTime($date))->add(new DateInterval('P1D'))->format('Y-m-d');
```