# date() returning wrong day although the timestamp is correct!

Tags: php, datetime

I have a bizzare problem with php date function.

code:

```
$numDays = 8;
$date = strtotime('2010-11-06');
for ($i=1; $i<=$numDays; $i++)
{
    $thisDay = date("D, d M Y", $date);
    print ($thisDay.'<br>');
    $date+=86400; // add one day to timestamp
}
```

result on my server (local host, windows):

Sat, 06 Nov 2010

Sun, 07 Nov 2010

Mon, 08 Nov 2010

Tue, 09 Nov 2010

Wed, 10 Nov 2010

Thu, 11 Nov 2010

Fri, 12 Nov 2010

Sat, 13 Nov 2010

Result on my web server (linux)

Sat, 06 Nov 2010

*Sun, 07 Nov 2010

Sun, 07 Nov 2010*

Mon, 08 Nov 2010

Tue, 09 Nov 2010

Wed, 10 Nov 2010

Thu, 11 Nov 2010

Fri, 12 Nov 2010

Notice how Sun, 07 Nov 2010 appears twice on the remote server?? Why is this happening? can anyone explain this Behavior?

Comment: 86400 seconds != 1 day. One has to learn this over and over again, unfortunately, for each of the edge cases: Daylight saving time, leap-year, leap-second, time zone crossing, travelling near light speed...

Comment: +1 for traveling light speed, reminds me of Einstein relativity principles !!

Comment: Literally speaking 86400 secods = 24 hours = one day :) Issues related to timezone are a different matter! Greetings to my second mother country :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

November 7, 2010 is the DST switch date in many time zones (but not Greece where you seem to be located). From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DST):

> Starting in 2007, most of the United States and Canada observe DST from the second Sunday in March to the first Sunday in November, almost two-thirds of the year.

In Greece, it seems to be [October 31](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone.html?n=26). Which time zone do you have you set on your machine?

Comment: You are right, if I set Athens timezone ( Europe/Athens ) the dates appear correct. However this means that if the user is in USA or Canada the above code will not work! if I use US/Pacific as timezone for example I get the wrong results. Is there a straightforward way to solve this?

Comment: @spiros I *think* `strtotime("+1 day");` will take DST into consideration.

Comment: If you're pulling the data from a database server, you might be better off doing the date manipulation there; Postgres, in particular, is good here.  Timestamps stores with a time zone can simply be cast into another time zone and the database handles all the daylight savings, etc (I don't think light speed, mentioned above, is accounted for, however) - more information at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES.  MySQL date functions tend to be, in my experience, relatively crap, but someone else may have more info.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to be certain here, but could you problem be caused by a daylight saving time transition in the remote server's timezone?

In most countries the transition usually happens on weekends and, since the day is extended by an hour, this is one case where adding 86400 seconds to a time value would *not* return the date after that.

Comment: Useful as a hint to set timezone, but Pekka's was more detailed and in depth so I accepted his. Thank you :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10155302)

Comment: @Nasreddine How would you suggest I improve this answer? I could edit it to provide the full solution to the author's problem, since now we know what caused it.

Answer (score 2):

It's good practice to do time calculations in UTC and then convert them to the required timezone for the user's location using PHPs datetime functions:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Athens');
$datetime = new DateTime('now', $timezone);
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1):

Run your code with the starting date +1 hr and then -1hr and see what results you get. You'll get more clues and most likely it is to do with Daylight Saving Time.

Also, as pointed out by Pekka, try the same with the date set to Oct 31st and see what happens.

Good question.