# if current_time is 1 day over logged_time php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [adding one day to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394791/adding-one-day-to-a-date)

I'm trying to add a day to a value pulled from a mysql row. 
so the value getting returned is let's say

```
2012-10-22 22:12:13
```

and I want to make it

```
2012-11-22 22:12:13
```

and store it in the variable without having to interval it back into mysql and then pull it right back out.

i tried doing

```
$end_date_add = $enddate + 0000 . "-" . 00 . "-" . 01 . " " . 00 . ":" . 00 . ":" . 00;
```

with $end_date being the time logged, but it replaces the time with zeros. 
am I going about this wrong?
Any help much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please use the search. This has been asked a thousand times. Thank you.

Comment: check [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want, i guess...

```
$date_old = strtotime("+1 MONTH", strtotime("2012-10-22 22:12:13"));

echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date_old);
```

Comment: Ah, I see the process. Thank you! :)

Comment: Any ideas on how I would go about multiplying a variable every day after? so, var on 1st day is 1, second day 2, third, 4, fourth, 8, etc?

Comment: so, you want to multiply a value everyday? 
First: you should have a reference starting date.

Comment: There is no need to call `strtotime` two times.

Comment: nope. you need to use `strtotime` 2x unless you want a wrong result...

Comment: He means strtotime("2012-10-22 22:12:13 +1 MONTH")

Comment: Right, answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13062416/367456 - you find demos to play with.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of *strtotime* to add the one month period:

```
$date   = '2012-10-22 22:12:13';
$format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
echo date($format, strtotime("$date +1 MONTH"));
```

Output ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ASKTHZ)):

```
2012-11-22 22:12:13
```

You can also make use of PHP's *DateTime* type and add a *DateInterval* of one day:

```
$date   = '2012-10-22 22:12:13';
$format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
echo (new DateTime($date))->add(new DateInterval('P1M'))->format($format);
```

Output ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/jmmB1A)):

```
2012-11-22 22:12:13
```

The code above is PHP 5.4, in PHP 5.3 you can do:

```
echo date_add(new DateTime($date), new DateInterval('P1M'))->format($format);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Date adding**

```
$date = date("Y-m-d"); // current date
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 day");
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 week");
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +2 week");
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 month");
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +30 days");
```

Comment: That is the problem, I don't want to get the date now, I want to use the date I have on file, in it's string format already and add 1 day, or 24 hours specifically.

Comment: So set a different input, it's just an example

Answer (score 0):

This could also be done as part of the MYSQL query

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(datecol, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS 'datecol_plus_one'
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was trying to initially avoid doing.

Comment: Fair enough, then sephoy08's answer will be the best