# Work out tomorrows date from any given date

Tags: php, date

I would like to work out how to calculate what the date will be after a given date for example this date:

```
$json->date = date("12/24/2012");
```

This doesn't work:

```
date('tomorrow', strtotime($json->date));
```

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394791/adding-one-day-to-a-date

Comment: good search, i spend around 5mins searching, my wording just wasn't correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work just fine

`$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2012-10-25")) . " +1 day");`

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)

```
$datetime = new DateTime('tomorrow');
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: thumbs up for the speed :) But i need to get what the day after a given date is