# PHP mktime() is returning wrong date

Tags: php, date, mktime

im doing some stuff with mktime, i need to add the next date with 30 days more but its returning me 1970-01-30 date, what im doing wrong ?

```
$strtime=strtotime("2013-10-04");
$fecha=date("Y-m-d",$strtime);
echo $fecha."<br />";
$nueva_fecha=mktime(0,0,0,date("n",$fecha),date("j",$fecha)+30,date("Y",$fecha));
echo date("Y-m-d",$nueva_fecha)."<br />";
```

Result:

> 2013-10-04
>
> 1970-01-30

Comment: does it have to be mktime?

Comment: Is there any other way ? i just need to sum 30 days and get the new date with it.

Comment: FYI, but I got this warning 3x on your mktime call: Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in date.php on line 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date is looking for a timestamp as it's 2nd parameter, not a string value representing this. Updated to pass it $strtime instead.

```
$strtime=strtotime("2013-10-04");
$fecha=date("Y-m-d",$strtime); // <-- Unnecessary unless you want to echo the value.
echo $fecha."<br />";
$nueva_fecha=mktime(0,0,0,date("n",$strtime),date("j",$strtime)+30,date("Y",$strtime));
echo date("Y-m-d",$nueva_fecha)."<br />";
```

Output:

> 2013-10-04
>
> 2013-11-03

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the following function to add 30 days to the date you put in:

```
$date = strtotime("2013-10-04");
$new_date = strtotime("+30 days", $date);
```

or simply to the current date:

```
$new_date = strototime("+30 days", time());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already have strtotime, why plus on `date` ? Instead you could've used + (30 days in seconds) OR simply the feature they offer you `+ 1 day` check answer: [adding one day to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394791/adding-one-day-to-a-date)

`strtotime('2013-10-04 + 30 days');`

This will print `2013-11-03`:
`date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2013-10-04 + 30 days'))`

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

echo strtotime("+1 day"), "\n";

echo strtotime("+30 day",strtotime(date('D, d M Y'))), "\n";

this will add 30 days to the current date.

Also strtotime is very usefull you can use it for weekly,monthly and yearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this also

```
<?php

$date      = date("Y/m/d"); // example date in yyyy/mm/dd format
$unix_time = strtotime( $date ); // covert date to unix time

$sec_in_30_days  = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30; // 60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours * 30 days

$new_unix_time   = $unix_time + $sec_in_30_days; // add 30 days to unix time
$date_in_30_days = date( 'Y/m/d', $new_unix_time ); // convert new unix time to date

// Output results:
echo 'original current date: ' . $date . '<br />';
echo '<br />';
echo 'new date: ' . $date_in_30_days . '<br />';

?>
```

Output will be

original current date: 2013/10/04

new date: 2013/11/03