# php inserting date and date +1 vars

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a book/library app. I want to give users the option of 'reserving' a book until the following working day (5pm). After this the book should become available again, that is another question for another day!

Currently once the user clicks '**Reserve**' I insert a number of records into my '*borrow_request*' table. These are as follows;

```
borrow_id
book_id
user_id
date_request
date_expire
```

My date_request variable is;

```
$date_request = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

How can I insert a `date_expire` variable and increment it by one working day?

The next step I will investigate is how to reset the `date_expire` after one working day, possibly a cron job?

Quite new to php/mysql here so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at `DateTime`

Comment: `$date_expire = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+1 day"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a cron job you should use mysql events which allow you to run queries after a certain amount of time. To add a day to the date you could:

```
<?php
$stop_date = '2009-09-30 20:24:00';
echo 'date before day adding: ' . $stop_date; 
$stop_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($stop_date . ' + 1 day'));
echo 'date after adding 1 day: ' . $stop_date;
?>
```

taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1394811/

for the question: [adding one day to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394791/adding-one-day-to-a-date)

You should have googled it first there are many answers here in stack overflow already like the one I'm posting

Comment: what is the proper place to write 'I agree with the change' in this site Fred? As comments shouldn't be used to thank and stuff like that