# Trying to add 24 hours to a date which is stored in a variable. PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a variable which is holding the output of a datepicker input tag. I want to add 24 hours to it.

As it stands, if I `var_dump` the variable it is:

```
string(10) "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

How would I go about adding 1 day to it?

I have tried:

```
$finishdate2 = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($finishdate . "+1 days"));
```

but I seem to get some weird dates.

Comment: where is your code and what you have tried for it?

Comment: I have tried: `$finishdate2 = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($finishdate . "+1 days"));` but i seem to get some weird dates

Comment: possible duplicate of [adding one day to a date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394791/adding-one-day-to-a-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$date="10/05/2015";
$date1=str_replace("/","-",$date);
$tomorrow=date('d/m/Y',strtotime($date1 . "+1 days"));
```

You can try like this

Answer (score 0):

You can try with it

```
$your_date_variable= str_replace('/', '-', $user_iput); 
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($your_date_variable. ' + 1 days'));//2015-05-14
or
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($your_date_variable. ' + 1 days'));//2015-05-14 11:07:07
```

Comment: This doesn't work with the user's input (`dd/mm/yyyy`).

Comment: use $your_date_variable= str_replace('/', '-', $user_iput);

Answer (score 0):

this will help you..

```
<?php
$date = '2015-02-28';
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . ' + 1 day'));
echo 'date after adding 1 day: ' . $date;
?>
```

Comment: This doesn't work with the user's input (`dd/mm/yyyy`).

Comment: use `str_replace('/', '-', $user_iput); `