# If $date = date_create_from_format(<!--some code-->), then how do I add a day to $date?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I've got a date:

`$date = date_create_from_format(<!--some code-->)`

I want to add a day to it like this:

`$date->add(+1 day)->format('F jS, Y')`

Here, "`->add(+1 day)`" is pseudocode for the desired function/operation to add a day to `$date`.
Not sure how to implement as I don't know what kind of object `$date` is or what procedure to use; *i.e.* "`->(some operation)`" or "`somefunction($date)`"

Comment: *I don't know what kind of object $date is* Why not check the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create-from-format.php ?! Also while you are in the manual maybe check the right side to see all methods this object has.

Comment: So, it's a DateTime object? A___n___d___, I use it like this: `$amount= new DateInterval('P1D');$date->add($amount);`

Comment: Yes, you can also check it with `echo get_class($date);`. And yes you add 1 day like this, but you can also just use `modify()` and write `->modify("+ 1 day")`

Comment: I think I'm going to try `->modify()`...

Comment: @Rizier123, Should this question be deleted?

Comment: Well there are already some Q&A's answering your question how to add 1 day to a date: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1394791/3933332 , but at the end it's up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example to add a day to now with `\DateInterval` :

```
echo (new \DateTime())->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'))->format('Y-m-d')
```

Comment: So `$date->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'))->format('F jS, Y')` would suffice?

Comment: Yes, if `$date`is an instance of `\DateTime`