# Php have function for plus date or not?

Tags: php, date

Php have function for plus date or not ?

normally, if i want to plus date with 5 day i usually user this code.

```
<?PHP
$now = date("Y-m-d");
$now_explode = explode("-", $now);
$now_year = $now_explode[0];
$now_month = $now_explode[1];
$now_date = $now_explode[2];
$now_date = $now_date + 5;
$next_five_date = $now_year."-".$now_month."-".$now_date;
echo $next_five_date;
?>
```

But i have some issue eg: if `$now = "2016-12-31";`. When i run my code. Result will be `2016-12-36`  Then i have to check month, check year for date in Feb month.

It's labyrinthine, so i want to know php have general function for plus date in to date ?

Comment: Use the date object http://php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php

Comment: Use the DateTime Object

Comment: If the `DateTime` object is too advanced for your needs, a simple `date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+5 days"))` will do the trick.

Comment: Great answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1394811/3063226

Answer (score 2):

Here's one of many ways to do it:

```
$now = date("Y-m-d"); //how to get current date
$next_five_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+5 days')); //how to get date +5 days
```

Comment: you could also add $now to the strtorime to make it better. `$next_five_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+5 days', $now));` This way $now can be later and it will still work