# add 1 day to date format YYYYMMDD when field name is greater or equal to 1200

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have 2 fields `dateUS and HourMins` (data type is `varchar`)

```
dateUS     | HourMins

20160928   | 0108

20160927  | 2144

20160902 |  0319

20160919  | 1215
```

**output will be**

```
dateLoc    

20160928

20160928

20160902

20160920
```

run to mysql query on my database

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adding one day to a date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394791/adding-one-day-to-a-date)

Comment: please post your code so that we could guide you..

Comment: SELECT CASE 
            WHEN HourMins >= 1200
               THEN add (1 day) 
               ELSE (remain)
       END as dateloc,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of `STR_TO_DATE` and `DATE_FORMAT` function you can achieve this:

```
SELECT 
 DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(dateUs,'%Y%m%d') + INTERVAL HourMins+0 >= 1200 DAY ,'%Y%m%d') 
  AS dateLoc
FROM your_table
```

---

**Demonstration:**

```
SET @str := '20160919';


SET @HOUR := '1215';

SELECT
    (
        STR_TO_DATE(@str, '%Y%m%d') + INTERVAL (@HOUR + 0) >= 1200 DAY
    ) AS date,
    DATE_FORMAT(
        STR_TO_DATE(@str, '%Y%m%d') + INTERVAL (@HOUR + 0) >= 1200 DAY,
        '%Y%m%d'
    ) AS expectedFormat;
```

**Output:**

```
date         expectedFormat
2016-09-20     20160920
```