# Add Days in format d/m/Y

Tags: php, date, days

I want how to add days, I try this

```
$start = '06/07/2017'
echo $start;
echo "<br>";
echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime(' + 1 days', strtotime($start)));
```

But return this

```
06/07/2017
08/06/2017
```

What is the problem?

Comment: try +1 day maybe !

Comment: You could use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com) library to make your life easier with date and times

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394791/adding-one-day-to-a-date

Comment: I would propose this too : + (3600*24)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?php
$start = '06/07/2017';
echo $start;
$start = str_replace("/","-",$start);
echo "<br>";
echo date("d/m/y", strtotime(date('d-m-Y', strtotime(' + 1 days', strtotime($start)))));
```

**Note: Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and the separator is a dash (-, the date string is parsed as y-m-d.**

Source [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
//old code
$str = '06/07/2017';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $str);
$start_old =  $date->format('d-m-Y'); 
echo   date('d/m/Y', strtotime($start_old . ' +1 day'));
echo "<br>";
//new updated code
$start = '06/07/2017';
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $start)
    ->add(new DateInterval('P1D'))
    ->format('d/m/Y');
?>
```

Using [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

[fiddle](https://eval.in/742183)

Comment: Better to use `dateTime::add()` and `dateTime::format()` since you're already passing the date string into a `DateTime` object.

Comment: you can improve my ans @CD001

Comment: Hope that's OK ;)

Comment: It's  Working @CD001