# adding one day to a custom formatted date string

Tags: php

I have a string in the format YYYYMMDDHH24MISS that is year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds.  I want to convert this to a date, add one day to it and return it in the same format.  Sounds simple but I am unable to get this to work.  I have tried a number of different ways where $field3 contains the date string for example:

```
                $end_date = strtotime(substr($field3,1,8));
                $date_interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
                $new_end_date = date_add($end_date, $date_interval);
                $field3 = ($new_end_date->format('YYYYMMDD')).substr($field3,8,6);
```

In this example $new_end_date contains "false".

Example date time string:  20170912124159 being 12/09/2017 12:41:59

Comment: What is the meaning of `24MI` in the date format? Update the question with some examples of input strings and their corresponding dates.

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394791/adding-one-day-to-a-date). This shows very easy ways to add a day to a date

Comment: I wouldn't rely on strtotime. You can control formatting directly with: $end_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', substr($field3,0,8));

Comment: `YYYYMMDDHH24MISS` looks like an Oracle format code, equivalent to PHP's `YmdHis`. You appear to be trying to discard the time part but then say you want it there. Could you please edit the question and clarify that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of your input string can be parsed by the constructor of class [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) (and [`date_create()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php) and [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)) without problems.

```
$date = new DateTime('20170912124159');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
echo($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

# The output is:
# 2017-09-13 12:41:59
```

You can, as well, format the date as string using the format `YmdHis` to get the modified date in the same format as the input string.

```
echo($date->format('YmdHis'));
# 20170913124159
```

Read about [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHis', '20170912131313');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P10D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

For more information: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

```
$date = date("Y/m/d H:i:s");   // or  '2017/09/30 20:24:00'
$ndate = date('Y/m/d H:i:s', strtotime($date . ' +1 day'));
echo 'date after adding 1 day: ' . $ndate;
```

Comment: why negative ? is It not working for you? or please correct

Comment: How is processed the input string in your code? [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) formats a date as string, the OP already has strings and want to convert them back to dates in order to process them. With only one argument `date()` formats the current time; the question doesn't care about the current time. Aren't these reasons enough to downvote?

Comment: @axiac in place of date you can give string also in the format it will work. See my updated answer.

Comment: You didn't get it. The question asks how to add 1 day to some dates represented in a format that **is not** `Y/m/d H:i:s` then format the updated dates in the same format. Your answer uses the wrong format and it doesn't care about the input strings. It always formats the current time +1 day. How do you think this is useful to the OP?