# Symfony add 1 day to current day

Tags: symfony

I want to get the actual time and add one day to it, setter below is datetime column type and it doesn't accept the date function. What should i do?

```
$password->setExpiretime(date("Y-m-d", time() + 86400));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding one day to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394791/adding-one-day-to-a-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `format` method on an instance of `DateTime` class:

```
$tomorrow = new DateTime('tomorrow');
$password->setExpiretime($tomorrow->format('Y-m-d'));
```

## Update

According to the comment submitted by the OP, if the return type should be `DateTime` Object, you may just use:

```
$tomorrow = new DateTime('tomorrow');
$password->setExpiretime($tomorrow);
```

Comment: Thanks for help but problem was other thing. It doesnt accept string, i put it without format method and works fine. One thing it is tommorow but not equal from now. Today's 20 tommorow is 21 but i want 21 15:04:23 , with time.

Comment: Ok i did it! new \DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() + 86400))

Comment: $password = new \DateTime();
        $password->modify("+1 day");

I don't like this workaround with date() and calculation.