# Failing to get daily sales between two dates after midnight - codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

Am failing to retrieve **DAILY SALES** in my **codeigniter 4 pos system** after mid night when query between two dates.

The POS system is working in the BAR/Club where their start time is 14:00 and end time is 03:00 (next day).

My current code only shows daily sales upto midnight. After mid night my opening hours change to new day returning nothing because no sales by then.

Here is what I tried

## **MODEL**

```
//Get Daily Sales For Tenant ID - By Specific Opening/Closing time
    public function getdailySalesByTenant($t, $ot, $ct)
    {
        $builder = $this->db->table('orders as o');
        $builder->select('o.*, u.first_name as waiter');
        $builder->join('users as u', 'u.id = o.sold_by', 'left' );
        $builder->where('o.tenant_id', $t);
        $builder->where('o.created_at >=', $ot); 
        $builder->where('o.created_at <=', $ct);
        return $results = $builder->get()->getResult();
    }
```

## **CONTROLLER**

```
//Daily Sales
    public function getdailySales()
    {
        $t = $this->settingsModel->where('user_id', $this->tenantId->tenant_id)->first();
        $ot = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($t['opening_time']));
        $ct = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($t['closing_time'].'+ 1 day'));
        
        $data = $this->transactionsModel->getdailySalesByTenant($this->tenantId->tenant_id, $ot, $ct);
        $response = [
                'success' => true,
                'data' => $data,
        ];
        return $this->response->setJSON($response);
    }
```

I want to record daily sales from 2023-01-05 14:00:00 to 2023-01-06 03:00:00

Comment: if time < 3 subtract 4 from datetime..

Comment: @P.Salmon thanks for the reply. Could you please provide more details on how i can fit that in the controller. Thank you

Comment: What does `$t['closing_time']` look like?

Comment: hi @steven7mwesigwa $t['closing_time'] is set in settings at is 14:00 (24hr format

Comment: hi @steven7mwesigwa $t['closing_time'] is set in settings at is 14:00 (24hr format

Comment: If your `$t['closing_time']` lucks the date segment, how do you set the *`2023-01-06 03:00:00`* upper bound then?

Comment: In addition, how do you know that `$t['closing_time'] = '14:00'` refers to the current day or the next day?

Comment: Good question Steven. On each sale. I record the DATETIME as you saw in the Model "created_at".  Because i want only the Daily sales report for that particular USER or Client. I have decided to use his WORKING Hours and ADD it on say TODAY's date as you can see here date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($t['opening_time']));.  this will print 2023-01-05 14:00:00 if you try it out.  Do not forget that $t['opening_time'] is SET already in user's settings and i pick it with $t = $this->settingsModel->where('user_id', $this->tenantId->tenant_id)->first();.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:❌

```php
// ...
$ot = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($t['opening_time']));
$ct = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($t['closing_time'].'+ 1 day'));
// ...
```

Use this:✅

```php
$ot = (new DateTime($t['opening_time']))->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$ct = (function () use ($t) {
    $openingTime = strtotime($t['opening_time']);
    $closingTime = strtotime($t['closing_time']);

    return ($closingTime >= $openingTime)
        ? (new DateTime($t['closing_time']))->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")
        : (new DateTime($t['closing_time']))->modify("+1 DAY")->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
})();
```

Reference(s):

1. [The DateTime class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#class.datetime)
2. [Adding one day to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394791/adding-one-day-to-a-date)

Comment: I replaced as you advised. It returns blank. But no error. However tried to do print_r($ct); and it was giving me "2023-01-06 04:00:00". Could it be that it is choosing only the last statement?

Answer (score 0):

When I use if --- else. it worked. Below is the Controller.

```
//Daily Sales
public function getdailySales()
{
    $t = $this->settingsModel->where('user_id', $this->tenantId->tenant_id)->first();
    
    $opening_hour = $t['opening_time'];
    $hour=date('H'); //24hr clock.
    if($hour < $opening_hour) {
        $ot = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($t['opening_time'].'- 1 day'));
        $ct = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($t['closing_time'].'+ 1 day'));
    } else {
        $ot = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($t['opening_time']));
        $ct = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($t['closing_time'].'+ 1 day'));
    }
    
    $data = $this->transactionsModel->getdailySalesByTenant($this->tenantId->tenant_id, $ot, $ct);
    $response = [
            'success' => true,
            'data' => $data,
    ];
    return $this->response->setJSON($response);
}
```